# How to get list of data items list from CRM Metadata Source in code behind?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, dynamics-crm-4

How to get list of data items list from CRM Metadata Source in code behind?

I have a CRm Metadata Source like

```
<crm:CrmMetadataDataSource ID="dsquestionOptionset" runat="server" EntityName="contact"
     AttributeName="securityquestion"/>
```

in the html.

I would like to get list of data items in the code behind from the datasource.

"securityquestion" is an intger value and this is linked to an option set.

I tried like

```
 var listOfItems=dsquestionOptionset.Items;
```

But not possible

Any help is appreciated

Vinu

Comment: I dont really understand what the question is, is the issue with querying Crm or displaying the results in your webpage?

Comment: I need all the list of data items of data source as a list to manupulate some functionlaities in the code behind.

I would like to get the list of datas as mentioned in the question.

Can I have any provision to implement in this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to query the Metadata.  An example (from here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg509035.aspx) would be something like:

```
RetrieveAttributeRequest retrieveAttributeRequest =
    new RetrieveAttributeRequest
{
    EntityLogicalName = Contact.EntityLogicalName,
    LogicalName = "new_picklist",
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

// Execute the request.
RetrieveAttributeResponse retrieveAttributeResponse =
    (RetrieveAttributeResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(
    retrieveAttributeRequest);

// Access the retrieved attribute.
PicklistAttributeMetadata retrievedPicklistAttributeMetadata =
    (PicklistAttributeMetadata)
    retrieveAttributeResponse.AttributeMetadata;

// Get the current options list for the retrieved attribute.
OptionMetadata[] optionList =
    retrievedPicklistAttributeMetadata.OptionSet.Options.ToArray();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion.
Unfortunately I forgot to mention about the method you have suggested.
I would like to implement this thing with a single line of code as shown in the question.

Any other suggestion?

Vinu

Comment: Sure, wrap this in a function and return the array.